# Where Can i Buy Bitcoins without using exchange?

Tags: marketplace

I'm Planning to work on a exchange where i dont want to connect to other exchanges. so where is the exact source or marketplace to buy/sell bitcoins without accessing any other exchanges . Any help plz reply ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Check localbitcoins.com, which is a site allowing users to interact and buy/sell from each other without the traditional exchange 'features'.

Comment: I Meant to ask "i need to make a node up and running for my exchange" which is already done "but how will i buy the bitcoins from a source" - except connecting to other exchanges -- i'm not a pro just have a doubt on ma head .. so kindly clarify it plz

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate (see @Nate Eldredge's comment)